Generic way to evaluate an unknown type in TypeScript
I manage the front end of an Angular 2+ website and I find myself frequently making API queries to backend systems and having to parse the responses. Those responses are of course very complex and differ from API to API.
As a consequence, littered throughout my code are parsing functions (like this example below), where all I'm doing is verifying that the expected fields actually exist in the object and that the types are correct.
type ExpectedReturnType = {
    a: string
    b: number
    c: boolean
}

function ParseApiResponse(res: unknown) {
    function isSomethingLike(given: unknown): given is Partial<Record<keyof ExpectedReturnType, unknown>> {
        return typeof given === 'object' && given !== null;
    }

    if (!isSomethingLike(res)) return null

    if (res.a == null || typeof res.a !== "string") return null

    if (res.b == null || typeof res.b !== "number") return null

    if (res.c == null || typeof res.c !== "boolean") return null

    let ret: ExpectedReturnType = {
        a: res.a,
        b: res.b,
        c: res.c
    }
    return ret
}

I feel like this sort of repetitive parsing should be possible to do in a Generic parsing function, but I can't figure out how to loop through the properties. Such a parse function might look like the following:
type ExpectedReturnType = {
    a: string
    b: number
    c: boolean
}

function ParseApiResponse<T>(res: unknown): T | null {
    function isSomethingLike(given: unknown): given is Partial<Record<keyof T, unknown>> {
        return typeof given === 'object' && given !== null;
    }

    if (!isSomethingLike(res)) return null

    for (/* iterate through props from T */) {
        // check for not null of prop
        // check for type correctness of prop
    }

    return res }

let ret = ParseApiResponse<ExpectedReturnType>({ a: 'str', b: 1, c: true })

Are there ways in TypeScript to create functions that loop through the properties of a type, or am I stuck with forever rewriting the same parse functions over and over that vary only in the properties they check for?

This isn't parsing; it's validation. See the linked q/a for the various ways to approach this. Either you use some kind of build plugin that converts TS types into runtime validation functions (outside tsc), or you have to use a tool that converts a schema object into TS types (inside TS code itself).

Type declarations don't exist at runtime so this is not possible. There are other tools you can use to validate schemas this is not something typescript can do alone.
